# Object properties lost when object passed to function

Tags: powershell

When an objet is passed in to a function, it seems to lose any properties of type `NoteProperty` that are associtated with it.

A simple test can reproduce this behaviour (code below), which results in the following output -

> Checking outside of function -
> Property exists.
> Checking inside of function -
> Property does not exist.

Is anyone able to explain why PowerShell is behaving in this manor, and how I can work around it to ensure that members I add are being passed to functions as expected?

---

## Code to reproduce above behavour

```
function Out-Object
{
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [object[]]$Object
    )

    Write-Output "Checking inside of function -"
    if ( Get-Member -InputObject $Object -Name "PropertyOne" -MemberType "NoteProperty" ) {
        Write-Output "  Property exists."
    } else {
        Write-Output "  Property does not exist."
    }
}

$newObject = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject
$newObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "PropertyOne" -NotePropertyValue "ValueOne"

Write-Output "Checking outside of function -"
if ( Get-Member -InputObject $newObject -Name "PropertyOne" -MemberType "NoteProperty" ) {
    Write-Output "  Property exists."
} else {
    Write-Output "  Property does not exist."
}

Out-Object $newObject
```

Comment: `[object[]]$Object` -> `[object]$Object`. The property isn't lost, but you're wrapping the object in an array, then check if that array has the property of its nested object (which it doesn't).

Comment: Or use begin-process-end structure of your function, to run process code for each object in `$object` separately, and thus get access to all its properties without extra hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ansgar stated, you're treating it like an array in your Out-Object function. You can either change

```
[object[]]$Object
```

to

```
[object]$Object
```

or you'll need to index the $object within your function

```
if ( Get-Member -InputObject $Object[0] -Name "PropertyOne" -MemberType "NoteProperty" ) {
```

Comment: Ah, of course.  Couldn't see that for looking, thanks for the heads up.